# SLD parsing fail on GeoServer

Tags: qgis, geoserver, sld

I created a custom style on QGis and saved as SLD file. When I added to GeoServer, after validation it, I got an errors about parsing.

Here is the error message below:

```xml
Parsing failed for Filter: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find function Literal
line 26: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ogc:Filter'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/ogc":expression}' is expected.
line 27: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ogc:Literal'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/ogc":spatialOps, "http://www.opengis.net/ogc":comparisonOps, "http://www.opengis.net/ogc":logicOps, "http://www.opengis.net/ogc":_Id}' is expected.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>Some_Name</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>Some_Name</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Single symbol</se:Name>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:GraphicStroke>
                <se:Graphic>
                  <se:Mark>
                    <se:WellKnownName>line</se:WellKnownName>
                    <se:Fill>
                      <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ff0000</se:SvgParameter>
                    </se:Fill>
                    <se:Stroke>
                      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ff0000</se:SvgParameter>
                    </se:Stroke>
                  </se:Mark>
                  <se:Size>3</se:Size>
                </se:Graphic>
                <se:Gap>
                  <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
                    <ogc:Literal>1.2</ogc:Literal>
                  </ogc:Filter>
                </se:Gap>
              </se:GraphicStroke>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ff0000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
            <se:PerpendicularOffset>1</se:PerpendicularOffset>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ff0000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
            <se:PerpendicularOffset>-0.6</se:PerpendicularOffset>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

How can I resolve the parsing issue?

Comment: More information about the data added to qgis, i.e. data type - format - also more about the custom style you created. please EDIT the original question with information that will help the investigation of this issue. Especially anything to help someone duplicate the problem.

Comment: i try to add the sdf file that exported from qgis. But accours parsing eror.

Comment: Are you seeing any red text within the xml after you validate?  This may help flag the problem section.

Comment: No, there isn't such a feature geoserver's editor, just showing validation parsing error info.

Comment: Geoserver supports SLD 1.1.0 only partly http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-reference/index.html Perhaps that could be part of a problem.

Comment: yeah it could be, i wonder is there a third party UI editor that create sld file?

Answer (score 3):

QGIS puts the filter tags but leaves out some essential parts that are needed by the validator in geoserver. So here's what you need to do:

in your filter tag add a PropertyIsEqualTo tag and within that add the PropertyName tag and the Literal tag.

So this:

```
  <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
    <ogc:Literal>1.2</ogc:Literal>
  </ogc:Filter>
```

Becomes this:

```
  <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      <ogc:PropertyName>FIELDNAME</ogc:PropertyName>
      <ogc:Literal>1.2</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
  </ogc:Filter>
```

Where FIELDNAME is the name of the field on which the filter is based. Then it should validate correctly.

Answer (score 2):

if you change the **StyleLayerDescriptor** to this...it does validate

```
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
```

It might look similar but geoserver is a bit odd when it comes to SLDs

Answer (score 0):

The parser is expecting an Expression at line 26 where you have a filter. So try removing the filter and just using the Literal (which is an expression).

I don't know if the GeoServer SLD parser will like it anyway as the Symbology Encoding support is patchy.

Comment: thanks @iant but no luck!, when i remove the 26. line  validation control is okay, but doesnt show on vector line :(