# GeoServer import SLD style from QGIS issue on 'se:Stroke'

Tags: qgis, geoserver, sld

GeoServer (2.14.3) gives me the following error:

> line 29: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'se:Stroke'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/se":VendorOption}' is expected.

when trying to import the following (SLD) style (created with QGIS):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
 <NamedLayer>
  <se:Name>Arsinoes-geopackage-vectors Structures</se:Name>
  <UserStyle>
   <se:Name>Arsinoes-geopackage-vectors Structures</se:Name>
   <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    <se:Rule>
     <se:Name>Graben/fissure</se:Name>
     <se:Description>
      <se:Title>Graben/fissure</se:Title>
     </se:Description>
     <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
      <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       <ogc:PropertyName>Structure</ogc:PropertyName>
       <ogc:Literal>graben/fissure</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
     </ogc:Filter>
     <se:LineSymbolizer>
      <se:Stroke>
       <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
       <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
       <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
       <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
      </se:Stroke>
     </se:LineSymbolizer>
     <se:LineSymbolizer>
      <se:VendorOption name="placement">centralPoint</se:VendorOption>
      <se:Stroke>
       <se:GraphicStroke>
        <se:Graphic>
         <se:Mark>
          <se:WellKnownName>circle</se:WellKnownName>
          <se:Fill>
           <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
          </se:Fill>
          <se:Stroke>
           <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
           <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
          </se:Stroke>
         </se:Mark>
         <se:Size>5</se:Size>
        </se:Graphic>
       </se:GraphicStroke>
      </se:Stroke>
     </se:LineSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
    <se:Rule>
     <se:Name>Wrinkle ridge</se:Name>
     <se:Description>
      <se:Title>Wrinkle ridge</se:Title>
     </se:Description>
     <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
      <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       <ogc:PropertyName>Structure</ogc:PropertyName>
       <ogc:Literal>wrinkle ridge</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
     </ogc:Filter>
     <se:LineSymbolizer>
      <se:Stroke>
       <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ff00ff</se:SvgParameter>
       <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
       <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
       <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
      </se:Stroke>
     </se:LineSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
    <se:Rule>
     <se:Name>Crater rim</se:Name>
     <se:Description>
      <se:Title>Crater rim</se:Title>
     </se:Description>
     <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
      <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       <ogc:PropertyName>Structure</ogc:PropertyName>
       <ogc:Literal>Crater rim</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
     </ogc:Filter>
     <se:LineSymbolizer>
      <se:Stroke>
       <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
       <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
       <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
       <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
      </se:Stroke>
     </se:LineSymbolizer>
     <se:LineSymbolizer>
      <se:Stroke>
       <se:GraphicStroke>
        <se:Graphic>
         <se:Mark>
          <se:WellKnownName>line</se:WellKnownName>
          <se:Fill>
           <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ff0000</se:SvgParameter>
          </se:Fill>
          <se:Stroke>
           <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
           <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
          </se:Stroke>
         </se:Mark>
         <se:Size>3</se:Size>
        </se:Graphic>
        <se:Gap>
         <ogc:Literal>18</ogc:Literal>
        </se:Gap>
       </se:GraphicStroke>
      </se:Stroke>
     </se:LineSymbolizer>
     <se:LineSymbolizer>
      <se:Stroke>
       <se:GraphicStroke>
        <se:Graphic>
         <se:Mark>
          <se:WellKnownName>line</se:WellKnownName>
          <se:Fill>
           <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ff0000</se:SvgParameter>
          </se:Fill>
          <se:Stroke>
           <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
           <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
          </se:Stroke>
         </se:Mark>
         <se:Size>3</se:Size>
         <se:Displacement>
          <se:DisplacementX>1</se:DisplacementX>
          <se:DisplacementY>0</se:DisplacementY>
         </se:Displacement>
        </se:Graphic>
        <se:Gap>
         <ogc:Literal>18</ogc:Literal>
        </se:Gap>
       </se:GraphicStroke>
      </se:Stroke>
     </se:LineSymbolizer>
     <se:LineSymbolizer>
      <se:Stroke>
       <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
       <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
       <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
       <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
      </se:Stroke>
     </se:LineSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
   </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
  </UserStyle>
 </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

It doesn't make sense to me, though, since `Stroke` is being defined at http://www.opengis.net/se (redirected to http://schemas.opengis.net/se/1.1.0/Symbolizer.xsd).

I saw these answers:

- [GeoServer 2.5 style SLD import from QGIS issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162556)
- [SLD parsing fail on GeoServer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102175/sld-parsing-fail-on-geoserver/291495#291495)

but I do not know how they apply to my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order is important in SLD (and XML in general) - the [SE specification](https://www.ogc.org/standards/se#overview) requires that `VendorOption`s come at the end of the Symbolizer they are in, so the error is actually saying - "You have started with `VendorOption`s so you can't go onto `Stroke`s!".

GeoServer is lenient when it comes to processing SLD files so this file will work but it is invalid as the validate process says. If you want it to be valid move the `VendorOption` line below the `Stroke` block. If you want to avoid having to do it again [raise an issue with the QGIS team](https://github.com/qgis/qgis/issues).