# SLD GeoServer VendorOption

Tags: geoserver, sld

I try create SLD style in QGIS and export to GeoServer.
And I have trouble with VendorOption name="placement">lastPoint<

Yes, I readed [GeoServer import SLD style from QGIS issue on 'se:Stroke'](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364986/geoserver-import-sld-style-from-qgis-issue-on-sestroke) this question and come at the end of the Symbolizer VendorOption but it isn't work.

sld look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1.0" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>bridges</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>bridges</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Single symbol</se:Name>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">4</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:GraphicStroke>
                <se:Graphic>
                  <se:Mark>
                    <se:WellKnownName>arrowhead</se:WellKnownName>
                    <se:Fill>
                      <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ff0000</se:SvgParameter>
                    </se:Fill>
                    <se:Stroke>
                      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
                      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">2</se:SvgParameter>
                    </se:Stroke>
                  </se:Mark>
                  <se:Size>11</se:Size>
                  <se:Rotation>
                    <ogc:Literal>180</ogc:Literal>
                  </se:Rotation>
                </se:Graphic>
              </se:GraphicStroke>
            </se:Stroke>
            <se:VendorOption name="placement">lastPoint</se:VendorOption>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:GraphicStroke>
                <se:Graphic>
                  <se:Mark>
                    <se:WellKnownName>arrowhead</se:WellKnownName>
                    <se:Fill>
                      <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ff0000</se:SvgParameter>
                    </se:Fill>
                    <se:Stroke>
                      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
                      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">2</se:SvgParameter>
                    </se:Stroke>
                  </se:Mark>
                  <se:Size>11</se:Size>
                </se:Graphic>
              </se:GraphicStroke>
            </se:Stroke>
            <se:VendorOption name="placement">firstPoint</se:VendorOption>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">2</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Desired result on pic

[image]

but I have this

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify - is the issue that the entire dataset doesn't display? Or is the actual issue that you want the symbology to be exactly the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok thanks i do it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> <StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<NamedLayer>
    <Name>bridge</Name>
    <UserStyle>
        <Title>bridge</Title>
        <FeatureTypeStyle>
            <Rule>
                <Name>bridge</Name>
                <LineSymbolizer>
                    <Stroke>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</CssParameter>
                    </Stroke>
                </LineSymbolizer>
                <PointSymbolizer>
                    <Geometry>
                        <ogc:Function name="endPoint">
                            <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </ogc:Function>
                    </Geometry>
                    <Graphic>
                          <Mark>
                            <WellKnownName>arrowhead</WellKnownName>
                            <Fill>
                            </Fill>
                            <Stroke>
                              <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
                              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</CssParameter>
                            </Stroke>
                          </Mark>
                          <Size>20</Size>
                        <Rotation>
         <ogc:Add> 
          <ogc:Function name="startAngle"> 
            <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName> 
          </ogc:Function> 
          <ogc:Literal>180.0</ogc:Literal> 
        </ogc:Add> 
                            </Rotation>
                    </Graphic>
                </PointSymbolizer>
                <PointSymbolizer>
                    <Geometry>
                        <ogc:Function name="startPoint">
                            <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </ogc:Function>
                    </Geometry>
                    <Graphic>
                          <Mark>
                            <WellKnownName>arrowhead</WellKnownName>
                            <Fill>
                            </Fill>
                            <Stroke>
                              <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
                              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</CssParameter>
                            </Stroke>
                          </Mark>
                          <Size>20</Size>
                        <Rotation>
                                                           <ogc:Function name="endAngle">
                                <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                            </ogc:Function>
                        </Rotation>
                    </Graphic>
                </PointSymbolizer>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">4</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
          </Rule>
        </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
</NamedLayer>
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of `VendorOption` is to warn you that it is something a vendor has added to the standard and that it probably won't work if you move to a different vendor (i.e. from QGis to GeoServer).

If you want to add a symbol to the beginning and end of the line in GeoServer then you need to use a function to transform your line into a point (`Start_Point` and `End_Point`) along with the related functions to give you the correct angle as described in this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/116716/79).