# Geoserver SLD parsing error on filter

Tags: geoserver, style, sld

I'm wortking with GeoServer Version 2.20.4 and I have uploaded an SLD file generated with QGIS 3.22.9-Białowieża. When validating the code, however, I get the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for Filter: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable 
to find function PropertyName
```

This is my SLD code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" version="1.1.0" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld 
http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
instance" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
<NamedLayer>
<se:Name>atlas_nuevo</se:Name>
<UserStyle>
  <se:Name>atlas_nuevo</se:Name>
  <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    <se:Rule>
      <se:Name>atlas_sacre_sacin_noctua</se:Name>
      <se:Description>
        <se:Title>atlas_sacre_sacin_noctua</se:Title>
      </se:Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:PropertyName>atlas_sacre_sacin_noctua</ogc:PropertyName>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        <se:Fill>
          <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#b506a9</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Fill>
        <se:Stroke>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Stroke>
      </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
    <se:Rule>
      <se:Name>atlas_sacre_sacin</se:Name>
      <se:Description>
        <se:Title>atlas_sacre_sacin</se:Title>
      </se:Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyName>atlas_sacre_sacin</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>atlas_sacre_sacin_noctua</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        <se:Fill>
          <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#3241c8</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Fill>
        <se:Stroke>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Stroke>
      </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
    <se:Rule>
      <se:Name>atlas_sacre</se:Name>
      <se:Description>
        <se:Title>atlas_sacre</se:Title>
      </se:Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:And>
            <ogc:PropertyName>atlas_sacre</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>atlas_sacre_sacin</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsNull>
                <ogc:PropertyName>atlas_sacre_sacin</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:PropertyIsNull>
            </ogc:Or>
          </ogc:And>
          <ogc:Or>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>atlas_sacre_sacin_noctua</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyIsNull>
              <ogc:PropertyName>atlas_sacre_sacin_noctua</ogc:PropertyName>
            </ogc:PropertyIsNull>
          </ogc:Or>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        <se:Fill>
          <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#9bd7ff</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Fill>
        <se:Stroke>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Stroke>
      </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
    <se:Rule>
      <se:Name>alternativas</se:Name>
      <se:Description>
        <se:Title>alternativas</se:Title>
      </se:Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>atlas_sacre</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        <se:Fill>
          <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#cbffc1</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Fill>
        <se:Stroke>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Stroke>
      </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
    <se:Rule>
      <se:Name>selección_sacre</se:Name>
      <se:Description>
        <se:Title>selección_sacre</se:Title>
      </se:Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:PropertyName>selecc_sacre</ogc:PropertyName>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        <se:Fill>
          <se:GraphicFill>
            <se:Graphic>
              <se:Mark>
                <se:WellKnownName>horline</se:WellKnownName>
                <se:Stroke>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ff8d01</se:SvgParameter>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Stroke>
              </se:Mark>
              <se:Size>13</se:Size>
              <se:Rotation>
                <ogc:Literal>45</ogc:Literal>
              </se:Rotation>
            </se:Graphic>
          </se:GraphicFill>
        </se:Fill>
      </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
    <se:Rule>
      <se:Name>sacre_profesional</se:Name>
      <se:Description>
        <se:Title>sacre_profesional</se:Title>
      </se:Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>Profesionales sacre</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>X</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <se:PointSymbolizer>
        <se:Graphic>
          <se:Mark>
            <se:WellKnownName>circle</se:WellKnownName>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ff0000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">0</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ff0101</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:Mark>
          <se:Size>29</se:Size>
        </se:Graphic>
      </se:PointSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
    <se:Rule>
      <se:TextSymbolizer>
        <se:Label>
          <ogc:PropertyName>utm_nueva</ogc:PropertyName>
        </se:Label>
        <se:Font>
          <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">MS Shell Dlg 2</se:SvgParameter>
          <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">13</se:SvgParameter>
          <se:SvgParameter name="font-weight">bold</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Font>
        <se:LabelPlacement>
          <se:PointPlacement>
            <se:AnchorPoint>
              <se:AnchorPointX>0</se:AnchorPointX>
              <se:AnchorPointY>0.5</se:AnchorPointY>
            </se:AnchorPoint>
          </se:PointPlacement>
        </se:LabelPlacement>
        <se:Halo>
          <se:Radius>1</se:Radius>
          <se:Fill>
            <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#fafafa</se:SvgParameter>
          </se:Fill>
        </se:Halo>
        <se:Fill>
          <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#323232</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Fill>
        <se:VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">1</se:VendorOption>
      </se:TextSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
  </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>
```

Following the suggestions given in this thread [SLD parsing fail on GeoServer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102175/sld-parsing-fail-on-geoserver), I have included (not understanding what I was doing, I confess), I included a `PropertyIsEqualTo` tag whithin the first filter, which returns

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for PropertyIsEqualTo: 
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
```

How should it be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

```
  <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
    <ogc:PropertyName>atlas_sacre_sacin_noctua</ogc:PropertyName>
  </ogc:Filter>
```

is not a valid filter so the error is correct.

Comment: OK. Any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: The QGIS style exporter must be fixed. You might want to open a bug report at the QGIS project. As a possible alternative, try out the GeoCat Bridge plugin, it also exports styles, but with a different generator, you might be more successful (or not, up to you to find out).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to hand-fix it, there is a good chance this may work:

```
 <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
    <ogc:PropertyName>atlas_sacre_sacin_noctua</ogc:PropertyName>
    <ogc:Literal>True</ogc:Literal>
  </ogc:Filter>
```

My guess here is that `atlas_sacre_sacin_noctua` is a boolean property, and  QGIS cannot tell the difference between a boolean expression and a filter (they are two different things in SLD).